# Excepcion al poner un layout usando xaml xamarin con aplicacion android

Tags: android, xamarin, layout

Buenas tardes,

tengo este codigo:

```
    <forms:SignaturePadCanvasView
    BackgroundColor="Black"
    WidthRequest="250"
    HeightRequest="350"
    StrokeColor="White"
    StrokeWidth="3"
    />
    <Button Text="test"
        Clicked="onclick" />
```

y al poner el layout para ver los dos controles, me salta una excepcion diciendo que no encuentra en ...2014/forms la info del layout usado:

```
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"    
    android:rowCount="2"
    android:columnCount="2">


    <forms:SignaturePadCanvasView
    BackgroundColor="Black"
    WidthRequest="250"
    HeightRequest="350"
    StrokeColor="White"
    StrokeWidth="3"
    />
    <Button Text="test"
        Clicked="onclick" />

</GridLayout>
```

Unhandled Exception:

Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XamlParseException: Position 8:6. Type GridLayout not found in xmlns http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms

¿Alguna idea de lo que puede estar pasando?

Gracias

Comment: No esta claro cual es el error . Puedes editar tu pregunta y agregar el mensaje de error completo?

Answer (score 0):

Lo que pasa es que estás mezclando XAML con Android XML (AXML). Xamarin Forms usa XAML para diagramar las páginas, que se generarán en tiempo de ejecución con los controles nativos de la respectiva plataforma. Las páginas XAML van en un proyecto de tipo compartido, PCL o NetStandard. Los layouts de android van en el proyecto de tipo Xamarin Android y ahí se crean en Resources\Layout con extensión AXML.

XAML no tiene GridLayout, pero existe un [Grid](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.Grid/) que es muy similar.

Una página de ejemplo en XAML para incluir SignaturePad es así:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:App2"
         xmlns:forms1="clr-namespace:SignaturePad.Forms;assembly=SignaturePad.Forms"
         x:Class="App2.MainPage">

<StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">

    <forms1:SignaturePadView
        x:Name="Pad"
        BackgroundColor="Gray"
        WidthRequest="100"
        HeightRequest="100"
        StrokeColor="White"
        StrokeWidth="3"
        PromptText="Prompt here"
        PromptTextColor="red"
        CaptionText="Caption this"
        CaptionTextColor="Black"

    />

    <Button Text="foo" Clicked="foobar" />
</StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

Comment: Perfecto gracias. No tenia esa informacion. Estoy empezando con este tema.